# "...both interact with their partner..." or "...both interact with their partners...."?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammatical-number

So my thesis for an essay is,

> **The American and Lane both interact with their partners** in different ways and want them to have an abortion, however, Lane faces much more internal conflict, nevertheless, their partners both end up going through with the same decision of having an abortion.

Should "partners" be singular or plural? They both have different partners (girlfriends).

Comment: As side notes, *an abortion* should be *abortions,* unless you specify *each.* And one uses a space before open parenthesis. But yes, Plural *partners* is correct, since there are more than one.

Comment: Can I recommend breaking it up into (at least) two sentences.  Even if you get all the plurals/singulars correct, it's still a horrendous long sentence to parse.

Comment: Sorry, Alex. There is nothing clearly acceptable about that passage, which means the Question *Should "partners" be singular or plural?* is pointless.

No part of the original should be kept… and no part can be corrected by itself.

Start by asking yourself how the Question title *Singular Or Plural? Thesis* is internally acceptable or in fact summarizes the detail.

The only thing obvious is that yes, *partners* is necessarily plural. How many *partners* do you think have parts in this story?

Comment: Similar: [“They're using a cell phone” vs. “They're using cell phones”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/301625)

Comment: It would only be 'partner' if The American and Lane were in a ménage a trois with one woman. Otherwise it's 'partners'.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by Davo, plural *partners* is correct, as there are more than one.

I also agree with Simon B's comment. You would do your reader a favour if you were to break the sentence up into two or more sentences so that it is more accessible (and parsable).

(Lifetime native English speaker and nearly as long as a book editor.)

Comment: The other commentators are being a little too kind about the two-sentence issue, What you have written has three independent clauses joined together without any proper conjunctions (neither "however" nor "nevertheless" serves here): it is an example of a *run-on sentence* and needs to be rewritten as two or three sentences. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_clause_structure#Run-on_sentences. And why not "in the end their partners both decided to have abortions" -- sounds less convoluted and less redundant to me than your wording.