# Singular or Plural: Artists with a hat

Tags: grammatical-number

Let's say we are categorizing people in a photograph. Which of these is correct?

1. Artists with hats
2. Artists with a hat

No artist has multiple hats.

The first option sounds better to my ear, but I'm not sure. Is either one definitely *wrong*? Why? Is there a name for this rule?

To make my example, a full sentence, I might say: "Please identify the artists with hats."

Comment: This aspect of grammar is called the _distributive plural_. There is an answer to a similar question here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/301625/theyre-using-a-cell-phone-vs-theyre-using-cell-phones/302499#302499

Comment: To disambiguate the sentence you could write: _Please identify the artists wearing a  hat_.

Comment: Bringing *artists* into the picture complicates things.

Comment: *Artists, each with a hat.*