# “Price of goods” vs “Prices of goods”

Tags: grammatical-number

I was just asked, in referring to the sentence: “The price of goods in big cities is usually higher than in small cities,” if it’s okay to swap “price of goods” for “prices of goods.” I said that goods is a singular group, and prices would only be acceptable if you put a modifying adjective that breaks the singular group into multiple groups such as “the prices of various goods in big cities,” but now I’m starting to wonder if that’s correct.

Comment: Its just a matter of singular and plural.

Comment: Your statement "*that goods is a singular group, and prices would only be acceptable if you put a modifying adjective that breaks the singular group into multiple groups such as “the prices of various goods in big cities*,” is correct but over-prescriptive: the plural implies the individual prices of individual goods, whereas the singular implies the generality of the price.

Comment: I'm guessing this question is a dup... (And it has nothing to do, per se, with prices or goods.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["They're using a cell phone" vs. "They're using cell phones"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/301625/theyre-using-a-cell-phone-vs-theyre-using-cell-phones). Here, “The price of goods in big cities is usually higher than in small cities” and “The prices of goods in big cities **are** usually higher than in small cities” are both fine and mean virtually the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The results yielded from the iWeb Corpus indicate that both are correct and that "goods prices" and "goods price" are also accepted but not so frequently used.