# Is it "the case" or "the cases"?

Tags: grammar

I'm writing a mathematical thesis and I have a theorem/sentence which is like

> This is proven for the case h = +/- 1.

So actually it is "the cases h = +1 and h = -1".

Here it is shortened to one term (which is actually two cases), should I use "case" or "cases" in the quoted sentence?

Comment: I'd go with "This is proven for the case h = +/- 1" meaning one case where h equals 1 or -1. Or with "This is proven for the equation h = +/- 1"

Comment: "Corollary for FLT n > 2: FLT is proven if FLT is proven for *all cases where* n is a prime." https://fermatslasttheorem.blogspot.com/2005/05/fermats-last-theorem-n-4.html   So you could say "proven for cases where h = 1 or -1".

Comment: Either is fine; the singular (where the plural might logically be expected) is called the 'distributive singular'. See [Everybody's using a cell phone nowadays vs Everybody's using cell phones nowadays](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/301625/everybodys-using-a-cell-phone-nowadays-vs-everybodys-using-cell-phones-now/548452#548452).

Comment: Either can be used, but which you prefer might depend on whether there are one or two proofs for the values. ±1 could be considered singular or plural.

Comment: You might want to check with your advisor on what is the preferred style.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that in English or maths, h = +/- 1 could reasonably be expressed as h = +1 and h = -1?

In any case, how could this purely mathematical Question belong in English Language & Usage?

Are you hoping to re-write the language of maths, or what?