# "uniform weights on all edges" or "uniform weights on each edge" or "uniform weight on each edge"

Tags: grammaticality

I would like to know which of the following sentences are correct, and why?

1. Our model places uniform **weights** on **all** edges in a graph.
2. Our model places uniform **weights** on **each** edge in a graph.
3. Our model places uniform **weight** on **each** edge in a graph.

Comment: Have you looked up the word? It can be countable and uncountable. I doubt yours is countable. Do you have a physical model with weights on it? I guess not...

Comment: You are using the wrong word. Either *Our model weights all edges equally in a graph* or *Our model places equal weighting factors on all edges in a graph*. *Uniform* is wrong, and *weights* is very informal as a noun here.

Comment: *Our model weights each edge in a graph equally.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(2) is best avoided. Consider

- (2') *The same books were read by each student*.

This surely defaults to each student reading books A, B, and C say: more than one book per student. While this is impossible for weighted edges (a 1 to 1 relation), (2) is at best clumsy.

In line with

- (1'') *All lines are of equal length*. being vastly more commonly chosen than
- (1') *All lines are of equal lengths*.

[[Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are+of+equal+length%2Care+of+equal+lengths&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3); there is correspondingly [a flatline for "are of equal weights"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are+of+equal+weight%2Care+of+equalweights&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) ] I'd also avoid (1).

That leaves (3).

The **distributive singular** is commonly available:

> The distributive singular may also be used to focus on individual
> instances. We therefore often have a number choice.
>
> - Some children have understanding fathers / an understanding father.
> - We all have good appetites / a good appetite.

[[Quirk et al; CoGEL; @Shoe's answer [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/301625/everybodys-using-a-cell-phone-nowadays-vs-everybodys-using-cell-phones-now)]

with an apparent number mismatch (some children ... have ... a father).

So

- (4) *Our model places [a] uniform weight on all edges in a graph.*

are also acceptable, even if 'weight' is seen as a singular count rather than non-count usage here.

So, to summarise, I'd use 'weight' rather than 'weights', but feel free to choose between 'on each edge' and 'on all edges'.

Answer (score 2):

I believe numbers 1 and 3 are correct but even number 2 gets the point across. It is either weights, plural for all, many, or weight, singular for each, individual.