Noun of noun agreement
I had a question regarding MLK's speech "I have a dream", and the following quote more especially:

I have a dream that my four little children will not be judged by the colour of their skin but by the content of their character.

My question is, since he has four children, why not use the plural here ? Would it be possible, as in "the colour(s) of their car(s) ? And if that's so, where would the "s" be, would it be at the end of "colour/content" or "skin/character" ?
If not, why ?

Possible, but awkward.  This is one of the most famous speeches ever given—something to learn from, rather than critique.

People have only one skin but may have more than one car. So, the singular is certainly justifiable. The grammatical topic is called the distributive plural. Here is a discussion of it that you may find useful: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/301625/everybodys-using-a-cell-phone-nowadays-vs-everybodys-using-cell-phones-now/302499#302499

There are lots of existing questions here about heads and bodies, as well as cars and phones, so this is probably a duplicate.

All the children have skin of the same color. Since there's only one skin color, it's singular.

But even if he were talking about children of different races, he's talking about color and skin as general concepts, which makes them non-countable.

The part of the speech including this quote is not in the text drafts, but is extemporaneous, which makes it of even more interest.
