# Single of plural nouns following the word "whose"

Tags: grammar

I am using "whose" to refer to the characteristics of a collection of things. Should the noun that follows the word "whose" be in plural or singular form?

These are my options:

> Except for videos whose *title contains* words related to a president, ...

> Except for videos whose *titles contain* words related to a president, ...

As per [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43820/proper-way-to-handle-plurals-with-whose), the second option is correct. However, it sounds a little silly in my head and thought it'd be better to ask a new question.

Comment: Hi @Chenmunka, thank you for referencing the post I linked to and stated that it did not fully answer my question. I suppose this means plural is correct.

Comment: "Videos whose title contains ..." is fine. It has a distributive meaning, where we understand that the title of each video of some set of videos contain words related to a president ...

Comment: But the plural is also correct. Singular and plural markings get swallowed half the time and ignored almost everywhere.